# What are the differences between the unary minus and unary tilde minus operators in ocaml?

Tags: operators, ocaml

I'm learning OCaml, and the docs and books I'm reading aren't very clear on some things.

In simple words, what are the differences between

```
-10
```

and

```
~-10
```

To me they seem the same. I've encountered other resources trying to explain the differences, but they seem to explain in terms that I'm not yet familiar with, as the only thing I know so far are variables.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, `-` is a binary operator, so some expression can be ambigous : `f 10 -20` is treated as `(f 10) - 20`. For example, let's imagine this dummy function:

```ml
let f x y = (x, y)
```

If I want produce the tuple `(10, -20)` I naïvely would write something like that `f 10 -20` which leads me to the following error:

```ml
# f 10 -20;;
Error: This expression has type 'a -> int * 'a
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

because the expression is evaluated as `(f 10) - 20` (so a substract over a function!!) so you can write the expression like this: `f 10 (-20)`, which is valid or `f 10 ~-20` since `~-` (and `~+` and `~-.` `~+.` for floats) are unary operators, the predecense is properly respected.

Comment: in fact, `-` is not always binary, e.g., in `1 - -2` we have `-` occurring as both unary and binary (prefix or infix in OCaml's parlance)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are obviously right but I was tempted to give a very straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to start by looking at how user-defined unary (~-) operators work.

```
type quaternion = { r:float; i:float; j:float; k:float }
let zero = { r = 0.; i = 0.; j = 0.; k = 0. }
let i = { zero with i = 1. }
let (~-) q = { r = -.q.r; i = -.q.i; j = -. q.j; k = -. q.k }
```

In this situation, the unary operator `-` (and `+`) is a shorthand for `~-` (and `~+`) when the parsing is unambiguous. For example, defining `-i` with

```ml
let mi = -i
```

works because this `-` could not be the binary operator `-`.
Nevertheless, the binary operator has a higher priority than the unary `-` thus

```ml
let wrong = Fun.id -i
```

is read as

```ml
let wrong = (Fun.id) - (i)
```

In this context, I can either use the full form `~-`

```ml
let ok' = Fun.id ~-i
```

or add some parenthesis

```ml
let ok'' = Fun.id (-i)
```

Going back to type with literals (e.g integers, or floats), for those types, the unary `+` and `-` symbol can be part of the literal itself (e.g `-10`) and not an operator. For instance redefining `~-` and `~+` does not change the meaning of the integer literals in

```ml
let (~+) = ()
let (~-) = ()
let really = -10
let positively_real = +10
```

This can be "used" to create some quite obfuscated expression:

```ml
let (~+) r = { zero with r }
let (+) x y = { r = x.r +. y.r; i = x.i +. y.i; k = x.k +. x.k; j =x.k +. y.j  }
let ( *. ) s q = { r = s *. q.r; i = s *. q.i; j = s *. q.j; k = s *. q.k }
let this_is_valid x = +x + +10. *. i
```

Answer (score 1):

OCaml has two kinds of [operators](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#ss%3Aexpr-operators) - *prefix* and *infix*. The prefix operators *pre*cede expressions and infix occur *in* between the two expressions, e.g., in  `!foo` we have the prefix operator `!` coming before the expression `foo` and in `2 + 3` we have the infix operator `+` between expressions `2` and `3`.

Operators are like normal functions except that they have a different syntax for application (aka calling), whilst functions are applied to an arbitrary number of arguments using a simple syntax of juxtaposition, e.g., `f x1 x2 x3 x4`<sup>1</sup>, operators can have only one (prefix) or two (infix) arguments. Prefix operators are very close to normal functions, cf., `f x` and `!x`, but they have higher precedence (bind tighter) than normal function application. Contrary, the infix operators, since they are put between two expressions, enable a more natural syntax, e.g., `x + y` vs. `(+) x y`, but have lower precedence (bind less tight) than normal function application. Moreover, they enable chaining several operators in a row, e.g., `x + y + z` is interpreted as `(x + y) + z`, which is much more readable than `add (add (x y) z)`.

Operators in OCaml distinguished purely syntactically. It means that the kind of an operator is fully defined by the first character of that operator, not by a special compiler directive, like in some other languages (i.e., there is not `infix +` directive in OCaml). If an operator starts with the [prefix-symbol](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#prefix-symbol) sequence, e.g., `!`, `?@`, `~%`, it is considered as prefix and if it starts with an [infix-symbol](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#infix-symbol) then it is, correspondingly, an infix operator.

The `-` and `-.` operators are treated specially and can appear both as prefix and infix. E.g., in `1 - -2` we have `-` occurring both in the infix and prefix positions. However, it is only possible to disambiguate between the infix and the prefix versions of the `-` (and `-.`) operators when they occur together with other operators (infix or prefix), but when we have a general expression, the `-` operator is treated as infix. E.g., `max 0 -1` is interpreted as `(max 0) - 1` (remember that operator has lower precedence than function application, therefore when they two appear with no parentheses then functions are applied first and operators after that). Another example, `Some -1`, which is interpreted as `Some - 1`, not as `Some (-1)`. To disambiguate such code, you can use either the parentheses, e.g., `max 0 (-1)`, or the prefix-only versions, e.g, `Some ~-1` or `max 0 ~-1`.

As a matter of personal style, I actually prefer parentheses as it is usually hard to keep these rules in mind when you read the code.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Purists will say that functions in OCaml can have only one argument and `f x1 x2 x3 x4` is just `((f x1) x2) x3) x4`, which would be a totally correct statement, but a little bit irrelevant to the current discussion.